# Is it possible to omit 'so' in 'so that' phrase?

Tags: phrase-meaning

This is a lyrics of an ccm song.

> This is amazing grace
>   This is unfailing love
>   That You would take my place
>   That You would bear my cross
>   You would lay down Your life
>   That I would be set free
>   Jesus, I sing for
>   All that You've done for me

When you see the third line, is it right that'That You would take my place' means
'in order that you would take my place'?
And if I'm right, then is it possible to omit 'so' from 'so that' phrase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the lyrics mean something different from what you are assuming.

"That You would take my place" means "the fact that you would take my place."

The lyrics are saying that Jesus's willingness to take the narrator's place on 
the cross is representative of grace and love.

---

It is grammatically acceptable to omit "so" from the phrasing "so that..." before some consequence or outcome, but it sounds very old fashioned. The lines

> You would lay down Your life
>
> That I would be set free

are are an example of this construction.
 I don't believe many native speakers would omit "so" in modern speech, but some exceptions include lyrics and poems, where language rules and style are more flexible, as well as quotes from older texts or when speaking in an intentionally outdated manner.

Comment: I agree on all counts.  Interestingly, these lyrics **do** include an example of an omission of "so," but not in "That you would take my place."  It's on the sixth line, which is connected to the fifth line: "You would lay down your life (so) that I would be set free."  And as mentioned in this answer, it sounds old-fashioned.  More specifically, it sounds like something you might read in an old translation of the Bible.

Comment: @Juhasz You are correct. I did not even read that far. -_-; I will note that in my answer.